# How to fasten armored cable to joist in tight space

Tags: electrical, wiring, cable-management

I have some armored cable (AC/MC) that needs to be fastened to the floor joist.  Very limited access.  I could probably reach in and swing a hammer a few inches, but no way to get a drill or screwdriver without busting up the ceiling.  I can use staples meant for NM cable?

Comment: If this is remodel does it really need to be fastened to a joist (open question)?  Maybe a palm nailer?

Comment: Oh, I thought it had to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do new wire runs in an existing ceiling need to be stapled down?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/99697/do-new-wire-runs-in-an-existing-ceiling-need-to-be-stapled-down) - Ha, I knew it was familiar, I asked the question.  The "armored" portion threw me off, but I don't think that matters (read answers in detail).

Comment: Remodels do not require staples if the Sheetrock/ plaster is in place.